# MutationObserver get removedNodes only

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I am trying to get a specific removed element attributes from a page which can have 0 - n copies and can be added dynamically. I started using *DOMNodeRemoved* event to initially then learned that this is deprecated and then moved towards *MutationObserver*. This is the sample of the code below -

```
var deletionObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
      var $target = jQuery(mutation.removedNodes);
      lodash.forEach($target.find("Node"), function (value) {
..............

//Call
deletionObserver.observe(jQuery('body').get(0), {childList: true, subtree: true})
```

**Problem** - I am getting too many nodes through removedNodes object, for example when I add a `<p>` element to page, mutationObserver returns a `<p>` node in removedNodes object. Similarly when I delete one `<p>`, I get one extra element in removedNodes object. Is there any other way to get removedNodes exactly. I tried comparing removedNode to jQuery("body") while adding `<p>` element. Something like -

```
if(jQuery("body").find($target).length > 0)
```

this didn't work, I am always getting zero. Any suggestions will help thank you.

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var deletionObserver = new MutationObserver(
  function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(
      function (mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(
          function(node) {
            console.log('The added node', node);
          }
        );
        mutation.removedNodes.forEach(
          function(node) {
            console.log('The removed node', node);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);

var container = document.querySelector('.container');
console.clear();

deletionObserver.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  var temp = document.createElement('p');
  temp.textContent = "I am a `p` tag";
  container.appendChild(temp);
  setTimeout(function() {
    temp.remove();
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

I am watching both when nodes are added and when they are removed.

The Mutation Observer is called *after* a node is added and *after* a node if removed.

But it gives you the nodes that are added and removed. So there is no need to look them up.

I am using the built in `forEach` for the array of mutations and the arrays of added or removed nodes. No need to use lodash. And it runs faster.

Also `document.body` is the vanilla JS way of doing `jQuery('body').get(0)` and it runs much faster.

Comment: The parent element I am watching is a text area (confluence page edit mode). So if I press enter a new line is added, but the mutationObserver is fired and it provides an element in removedNode object instead of addedNodes. 
I will use forEach and I just put jQuery('body').get(0) as an example.

Comment: If you are talking about a `<textarea>` element, they do not have any children elements. Instead all of its text is available through `element.value`. So a mutation observer will not track any changes. Instead you can use the `input` event to know when changes are made. If you are talking about a DOM element with `contentEditable` set to `true` then the mutation observer should work. Can you post more code so I can dig into this deeper. - More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: I was not talking in the literal sense, its a text area figuratively. Please see the video to understand what I meant by Confluence page edit mode - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yx2r1mzIuUU. Do you need the whole method? or something different than above.